# ListManager items insert from a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a list of the boss of a group of employees.Its a drop down list tha have all the currently boss,Here is the code of the the populating of the list:

```
ListManager.DataSource = lstBUAreas;
            ListManager.DataTextField = "Description";
            ListManager.DataValueField = "EDV";
            ListManager.DataBind();
            ListManager.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione -->", "0"));
            ListManager.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This list start at the Selecione value from default,i want the list to begin showing the currently boss from the system,i have a method that brings the EDV of the boss:

```
Clic edvBoss = GetClic();
            int colaboradorEDV = edvBoss.UserResponsible.EDV;
            User directBoss = new UserManager().GetUserDirectBossByEDV(colaboradorEDV, out objStatus);
```

I want the list to start with the default value the boss,i think i need to change the Items.Insert or the SelectedIndex:i'm trying something like this,but doest't work:

```
ListManager.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione -->", "0"));
            ListManager.SelectedIndex = directBoss.EDV;
```

or

```
ListManager.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Selecione -->", "0"));
            ListManager.SelectedValue = directBoss.EDV;
```

But both doesn't work,anyone have some idea what i could do?

Comment: Try `ListManager.SelectedIndex = colaboradorEDV;`

Comment: colaboradorEDV its the EDV of the employee,not from the boss.

Comment: And what is `directBoss.EDV` ?

Comment: After i use the method GetUserDirectBossByEDV,passing the EDV of the employee,i return in the variable directBoss the data of the Boss,so directBoss.EDV its the "Login"of the boss,the value of the list is also this login.